# Localhost cannot be accessed from browser

Tags: php, apache, localhost

I have worked on localhost all these while till I ran some updates on Windows 7 and restarted. Now I can no longer access to localhost from browser. But Aapache service is running. Showing on system tray. May I know what is the problem?

Error log:

```
[Thu Dec 16 00:33:35 2010] [notice] Parent: Received restart signal -- Restarting the server.
[Thu Dec 16 00:33:35 2010] [notice] Child 4248: Exit event signaled. Child process is ending.
[Thu Dec 16 00:33:36 2010] [notice] Child 4248: Released the start mutex
[Thu Dec 16 00:33:37 2010] [notice] Child 4248: All worker threads have exited.
[Thu Dec 16 00:33:37 2010] [notice] Child 4248: Child process is exiting
[Thu Dec 16 00:33:40 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) PHP/5.2.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Dec 16 00:33:40 2010] [notice] Server built: Oct 18 2010 01:58:12
[Thu Dec 16 00:33:40 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 4672
[Thu Dec 16 00:33:40 2010] [notice] Child 4672: Child process is running
[Thu Dec 16 00:33:40 2010] [notice] Child 4672: Acquired the start mutex.
[Thu Dec 16 00:33:40 2010] [notice] Child 4672: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Thu Dec 16 00:33:40 2010] [notice] Child 4672: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

I found that Local Address 0.0.0.0:80 is bound to PID 1476 which is httpd.exe

Comment: restart apache, check your HOSTS file, check if apache can listening on port 80 (check it's error log)

Comment: host file is already set 127.0.0.1 to localhost

Comment: restart apache and check apache log files

Comment: what does http://127.0.0.1 say??

Comment: reboot windows again !!! and see what you get ...

Comment: What does `netstat -a -n` show is listening on port 80?

Answer (score 1):

check if your hosts file under `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` has been changed by some other program  just a guess ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is an error of the DNS service. Have you tried to access the system using the PCs IP-Address or the IP 127.0.0.1 (like http://127.0.0.1)?

Answer (score 0):

Try forwarding port 80.

Also, restart the Apache server once.

En last but not least, a seengee suggested, if you'r running Skype, close it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen Skype cause this issue in the past as i think it falls back to port 80 by default if its main port is blocked. If you use Skype, try turning it off and check again

Comment: you would get a blank screen if skype was turned on before apache! Skype starts a webserver on port 80 of some sort. If you start apache before skype make sure port 80 is ready and taken by apache, then start skype and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs. Check the httpd instance and see if it appears to be functioning smoothly.

I had a similar problem a month back where the electrician killed the power to my computer and I wound up with a corrupt Apache and MySQL install. I had to re-install and copy the .conf files over to resolve the issue.

**Edit**

Considering this is an update, check your firewall to assure the update did not restore it to it's defaults (stranger things have happened).

Answer (score 0):

before you restarted, did you install anything? What other services are running? Check if port 80 is already taken ...

Comment: it shows 0.0.0.0:80 with state listening to pid 3228 which is apache2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Run notepad.exe as administrator. Open c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file.
put this line :

127.0.0.1    localhost

save the file. you should have localhost.

Other thing is misconfig in your httpd.conf.

open your httpd.conf (usualy in c:\program files\apache software foundation\apache2.2\conf).

check this line:

ServerName xxxxx:80

where xxxx should be localhost or 127.0.0.1
change it if necessary, and save. Restart apache services.